# Drawing the bars on a bar graph horizontally

Tags: android, androidplot

I've been looking through the AndroidPlot documentation and I haven't been able to find whether it's possible to draw the bars on a bar graph horizontally (starting on the y-axis rather than the x-axis). I found the FillDirection enum that has the LEFT value, but this is unimplemented and I'm not even sure if it's referring to what I'm looking for. Does anyone know if this is possible? If not, can I just flip the layout that I've put the graph on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported by Androidplot but is on the roadmap (albeit off in the distance). [Here's a link to the issue tracker](https://androidplot.jira.com/browse/ANDROIDPLOT-172) for this feature.